pgfplotstable: Change to multicolumn row depending on input data
Let's say I have a huge amount of data rows structured in a simple .csv and these data rows could be divided in different data types.
In the MWE I just added two types (typA & typB).
In case the row contains typA, the table should be printed as it is and shown in my result.
In case the row contains typB, this row should be a multicolumn row where only the content of the Description field is printed in center.
How can I achieve this with LaTeX? :)
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{mwe}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Type, Description, X-Pos, Y-Pos
typA, PowerSupply, 3590,  2000
typA, PowerSupply, 3590,  2500
typB, PowerSupply, 4250,  6070
typA, singleSwitch,5700,  6070
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\CSVDataRows{\pgfplotsretval-1} 

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
font=\ttfamily,%
col sep=comma,%
columns={Type,Description,X-Pos,Y-Pos},%
columns/Type/.style={%
column name=Type,%
string type%
},%
columns/Description/.style={%
column name=Description,%
string type%
},%
columns/X-Pos/.style={%
column name=X-Pos%
},%
columns/Y-Pos/.style={%
column name=Y-Pos,%
column type/.add={}{|}%
},%
column type/.add={|}{},%
after row={\hline},%
every head row/.style={before row=\hline},
]{\csvdata}%
\end{center}
\end{document}

RESULT

EXPECTED RESULT

EDIT
My Idea is to add something like this:
every column/.style={%
    assign cell content/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Type}\of{\csvdata}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{typB}}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecol}{2}}{%=> Just do this once!
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Content Description}\\\hline}
            }{}
        }{}
    },
},

Second MWE
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Type, Description, X-Pos, Y-Pos
typA, PowerSupply, 3590,  2000
typA, PowerSupply, 3590,  2500
typB, PowerSupply, 4250,  6070
typA, singleSwitch,5700,  6070
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\CSVDataRows{\pgfplotsretval-1} 

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
font=\ttfamily,%
col sep=comma,%
columns={Type,Description,X-Pos,Y-Pos},%
columns/Type/.style={%
column name=Type,%
string type%
},%
every column/.style={%
    assign cell content/.code={%
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Type}\of{\csvdata}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{typB}}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecol}{2}}{%=> Just do this once!
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Content Description}\\\hline}
            }{}
        }{}
    },
},
columns/Description/.style={%
    column name=Description,%
    string type%
},%
columns/X-Pos/.style={%
    column name=X-Pos%
},%
columns/Y-Pos/.style={%
    column name=Y-Pos,%
    column type/.add={}{|}%
},%
column type/.add={|}{},%
after row={\hline},%
every head row/.style={before row=\hline},
]{\csvdata}%
\end{document}

RESULT

But how can I get

A multicolumn starting from the first column
Suppress the second row with the Y-Pos information
Substitute Content Description with the real content of the description, in this case PowerSupply?


Could a solution with csvsimple-l3 and tabularray be acceptable for you?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  group-digits=integer,
  group-minimum-digits={3},
  group-separator={,}
  }

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Type, Description, X-Pos, Y-Pos
typA, PowerSupply, 3590,  2000
typA, PowerSupply, 3590,  2500
typB, PowerSupply, 4250,  6070
typA, singleSwitch,5700,  6070
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[no head,
centered tabularray =
{
colspec={cc*2{S[table-format=4]}}, 
columns={font=\ttfamily},
hlines,
vlines,
},
]{data.csv}{}{%
\ifcsvfirstrow{% header
  \csvcoli & \csvcolii
  & {{{\csvcoliii}}}
  & {{{\csvcoliv}}}
    }{% rows
  \IfCsvsimStrEqualTF{\csvcoli}{typB}{% multicolumn
    \SetCell[c=4]{c}\csvcolii&&&}{% other rows
    \csvcoli & \csvcolii
    & \csvcoliii
    & \csvcoliv}
        }
    }
\end{document}


You can also use csvsimple-l3 with an ordinary tabular, but with a trick, a 5th dummy column, to avoid problems with siunitx column type in the last column:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  group-digits=integer,
  group-minimum-digits={3},
  group-separator={,},
    table-number-alignment=center
  }

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Type, Description, X-Pos, Y-Pos
typA, PowerSupply, 3590,  2000
typA, PowerSupply, 3590,  2500
typB, PowerSupply, 4250,  6070
typA, singleSwitch,5700,  6070
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[
  head to column names,
  before reading = {\begin{center}\ttfamily},
  tabular = {|c|c|S[table-format=4]|S[table-format=4]@{}c|},% the last dummy column is necessary
    % due to csvreader-l3 problems, see documentation, Section 7.4 Tables with Number Formatting
  table head = {\hline Type & Description & {X-Pos} & {Y-Pos}&\\\hline},
  late after line = \\\hline,
  after reading = \end{center}
  ]{data.csv}{}{%
  \IfCsvsimStrEqualTF{\csvcoli}{typB}{% multicolumn
    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\csvcolii}
        }{% other rows
    \csvcoli & \csvcolii
    & \csvcoliii
    & \csvcoliv &
        }
  }
\end{document}


N.B. = The macro \IfCsvsimStrEqualTF is quite recent. If your distribution is not up-to-date, use \ifcsvstrcmp instead. In both examples above, the result doesn't change with the old macro.

Thanks for your response, I tested it with overleaf and I get A number should have been here; I inserted "0". error. Even if I use \ifcsvstrcmp And to use csvsimple-l3 seems to be a valid solution at all, but doesn't really fit in my overall concept. I have edited my question, maybe you could have a look in that direction. Anyway +1 for your help :)


I tested my MWEs on Overleaf and with  \ifcsvstrcmp they work. Which TeX Live version are you using? 2) I didn't understand your edit, I created a table exactly like the one after "expected result". What are your expected result actually?


TeXLive version change to 2023 made it working in overleaf :) You are absolutely right, the result for this MWE is as expected! The issue is, that my current project is much more complex and based on pgfplotstableNow, I'm struggling with combining your solution with my project. This is the reason, why I tried to explain what kind of solution I'm aiming to.

I think my questions was not clear enough... You did everything what you could do. So I will accept your answer. For my special case I have created another question with a better fitting MWE. Maybe this is more clear then.

@PascalS Thank you for accepting my answer, but in my solution the specific rows are not hard coded, their content is tested here: \IfCsvsimStrEqualTF{\csvcoli}{typB}{ <--- this means "if the value of the cell in the first column (of the current row) is "typB", then do...

Here is a solution for OpTeX users:
\createfile {data.csv}
Type, Description, X-Pos, Y-Pos
typA, PowerSupply, 3590,  2000
typA, PowerSupply, 3590,  2500
typB, PowerSupply, 4250,  6070
typA, singleSwitch,5700,  6070
\endfile

\def\p #1,#2,#3,#4#5 {%
   \ifx^#1^\else
      \isequal{typB}{#1}
      \iftrue
         \mspan4[|c|]{#2} \crl
      \else
         #1 & #2 & #3 & #4#5 \crl
      \fi
      \ea\p
   \fi
}

{\everyeof{,,,{} }
\table{|c|c|c|c|}{\crl
   \ea\p\input data.csv
}}

\bye


+1 Because it is a working solution, but I need a LaTeX solution. I edited my question.

OK, but LaTeX is just an extra complication.
